# How to use JS to inject CSS for specific system pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, css

So I know that it is possible to set all of the System pages to use a certain CSS file in SharePoint but I am trying to apply the CSS to only a select few of the system pages.  All of the other System pages I would like t use the default SharePoint CSS and then all of the normal site pages are using my custom CSS.

I know generally I need an if statement checking to see of the URL matches something and if that is the case it will apply the CSS but I am unsure as to how I need to write this exactly. Any help or links to help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo:**

```
if ((window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('testfolder') > 0))
    {
    
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.href = 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/Doc/testFolder/test.css';
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        head.appendChild(link);
    }
```

For modern experience,you could add a SPFX Extension to add the js file to page.
https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss(demo on add CSS file,you could change it to add JS file),

For classic experience,you could use pnp powershell add jslink.

**Demo:**

```
$username = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "Password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev -Credentials $cred
 Add-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name "JSLoadAfterSP" -Url /sites/dev/Doc/testFolder/test.js -Sequence 9999 -Scope Site
```

[download pnp powershell](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

Comment: This is super helpful thank you! I am going to try this out right away!

Comment: to be clear, 'testfolder' in the if statement is the string in the url I am looking for and then link.href is just the link to the css file from SharePoint? @Amos_MSFT

Comment: Yes,the link is the css file from SharePoint,the 'testfolder' in if statement you need to change to the unique attributes of page url.