# Unable to Hide column in SharePoint List View web part using JSLink Client-Side-Rendering

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink, client-side-rendering, list-view-web-part

I'm trying to hide a column in List View Web Part using JS Link with Client Side Rendering. I'm able to color or make formatting changes to the column, but not able to hide it. Below is the code snippet that I have tried but it just does not displays the value rather than hiding the whole column. Here I am trying to hide column **field2**

```
var is_display;
    (function() {
        function registerMyListTemplate(){
            var  is_display = '';
            var fieldContext = {};
            fieldContext.Templates = {};
            fieldContext.Templates.Fields = {
                "field1":{
                    "View": changeView
                },
                "field2":{
                    "View": hideField
                }
            };
            fieldContext.Templates.Item = renderListItemTemplate;
            SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldContext);
        } 
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerMyListTemplate, 'clienttemplates.js');
    
    })();

    function hideField(ctx){
        var op = '';
        if (is_display !== ""){
            op = "";
        }else{
            op = '<div>' + ctx.CurrentItem.field2 + '</div>';
        }
        return op;
    }
```

I also checked out a code which helps to hide the column in the **PostRender** function but it doesn't work if the List View Web Part has paging. It only works for the first page of the List View Web Part.

```
function postRenderHandler(){
    ["field2"].forEach(function(name) {
        var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname=" + name + "]")[0].parentNode;
        var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
        header.style.display = "none";
        for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test code:

```
<script>
(function () {
    
    function RemoveFields(ctx) {
        var fieldName = "Title"; // here Date is field or column name to be hide
        var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname=" + fieldName + "]")[0].parentNode;
        var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
        header.style.display = "none";
        for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length-1; i++) {
            cells[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function registerRenderer() {
        var ctxForm = {};
        ctxForm.Templates = {};
        ctxForm.OnPostRender = RemoveFields;
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();</script>
```

Test result:

[image]

**Updated:**

[image]

Comment: I checked out above code already, but it doesn't work when paging is present. For example, it works on page 1 of paging but not on other pages.

Comment: It works well in my environment,check the update.

Comment: Let me check it again and get back. Is it necessary to place the function 'RemoveField' in the onLoad ?

Comment: How can I make it work for mutiple list view webparts?

Comment: For modern experience,you could add a SPFX Extension.For classic experience,you could use pnp powershell add jslink.You could know more about this here:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281581/how-to-use-js-to-inject-css-for-specific-system-pages/281603#281603

Comment: I made it working by passing the incrementing the variable in `("[displayname=" + fieldName + "]")[0]`. Instead of 0 I added the variable which gets incremented as per number of list view web parts added.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @Asmos_MSFT answer, I was able to solve my issue. To hide a specific column in List View Web Part using Client Side Rendering with JSLink, use the below code.

```
var is_display;
    (function() {

      function postRenderHandler(ctx) {
        var fieldName = "field2"; // here Date is field or column name to be hide
        var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname='" + fieldName + "']")[0].parentNode;
        var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
        header.style.display = "none";
        for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length-1; i++) {
            cells[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }

        function registerMyListTemplate(){
            var  is_display = '';
            var fieldContext = {};
            fieldContext.Templates = {};
            fieldContext.Templates.Fields = {};
            fieldContext.Templates.Item = renderListItemTemplate;
            fieldContext.OnPostRender = postRenderHandler;
            SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldContext);
        } 
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerMyListTemplate, 'clienttemplates.js');
    
    })();
```

Make sure that the function that you want to run to hide on **OnPostRender** is inside **OnLoad** function. If it is written outside the **OnLoad** then it might not work.

To hide same column on all available List View webparts on the page then change your **OnPostRender** function as below

```
var web_part_count = 0 // declare as global variable.

    function postRenderHandler(ctx) {
                var fieldName = "field2"; // mention the column name that needs to be hidden.
                var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname='" + fieldName + "']")[web_part_count].parentNode;
                web_part_count = web_part_count + 1;
                var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
                header.style.display = "none";
                for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length-1; i++) {
                    cells[i].style.display = "none";
                }
              }
```

Before Implementing above code, make sure that the column position that needs to be hidden should be same across all the List View Web Parts present. The **web_part_count** variable gets incremented on the **OnPostRender** of each webpart hence it hides the column in each available web part on the same page.

To Implement it for multiple columns, you need to make changes to the **OnPostRender** function as follows

```
var global_arr = ['field2','field3'] // global variable

function postRenderHandler(){
    global_arr.forEach(function(name) {
        var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname='" + name + "']")[0].parentNode;
        var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
        header.style.display = "none";
        for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

In the above function, It will loop through each of the column mentioned in the **global_arr** variable. Make sure that column name you mentioned in the array are available on the List View Web Part.

Hope this helps someone.