# Sharepoint online powershell usercustomactions scriptblock not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, csom

I want to add a warning message at the top of the SP online site. For that i tried UserCustomActions using powershell, code is running without error but not working. I tried to add ribbon control that is working. I have enabled the allow script option in the admin site. Below i included the code for reference.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

Function Add-ScriptLinkAction([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,[String]$ScriptBlock,[int]$Sequence)
{

    $action = $Context.Site.UserCustomActions.Add();
    $action.Location = "ScriptLink"
    <#
    if($ScriptSrc) {
        $action.ScriptSrc = $ScriptSrc
    }#>
    
    if($ScriptBlock) {
        $action.ScriptBlock = $ScriptBlock
    }
    $action.Sequence = $Sequence
    $action.Name = "title"
    $action.Title = "title"
    $action.Update()
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}

$siteUrl = 'https://stginfotechchennai.sharepoint.com/sites/ProductQualityReseachCenter'
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
# SPO credentials
$context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName username@domain.com

Add-ScriptLinkAction -Context $context -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Sequence 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

For modern page,we need to use spfx extension to add js file to page.If your code is ok,classic page should work well.

Comment: Okay i will try this option

Comment: You can refer to this question：https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281581/how-to-use-js-to-inject-css-for-specific-system-pages/281603#281603

Comment: okayy i will check

Comment: I want this kind of solution in SP online : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/283533/sharepoint-online-add-a-notification-message-in-top-banner-of-the-site