# SharePoint online add a notification message in top banner of the site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, spfx

I want to display a alert message to users at the top of the site before site migration in SP online. In SP 2016 i have implemented using powershell usercustom actions that is working fine and i did the same in online, but here it is not working. Below attached the working version of SP 2016 image. Please suggest any solutions or approach.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could make the site read only while it is being migrated. This will show a banner at the top of the page and will ensure that users cannot make changes while content is being migrated. For more information, see the below article:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/01/sharepoint-online-make-site-collection-read-only.html

Alternatively, you could deploy the SharePoint Starter Kit solution to your tenant and use the Alert Application Customizer to notify users. This allows you to set your own notification message. For more information, please see below:

https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/documentation/components/ext-alert.md

Answer (score 1):

If you are capable of using [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview), here is one SpFx Extension that might be helpful: [Banner for Modern Team Site – SpFx Extension.](https://shivsquest.com/banner-for-modern-team-site-spfx-extension/)

This extension will show up a message on the top of the modern page, which will be retrieved from a separate json file.