# Unable to remove left navigation from a SharePoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I have a SharePoint Online page created with a template, which I cannot remove the left navigation pane from. (I can edit the list of links, but I want to remove the whole pane completely).

Ideally I would like to remove the left navigation panel from this page only. Not from the entire site.

Please suggest any workaround...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a modern SharePoint site, you can disable the Quick Launch by going to Site Settings > Navigation elements (under "Look and Feel") > Untick "Enable Quick Launch".

More information can be found in the article below, in the section "Turn the left-hand menu on or off for a SharePoint team site":

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca

Answer (score 0):

You could add js code to determine whether the page is the target page.If it is,then add the custom css(Use CSS to hide left navigation).

Demo:

```
if ((window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('testfolder') > 0))
    {        
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.href = 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/Doc/testFolder/test.css';
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        head.appendChild(link);
    }
```

Inserting this code needs to distinguish different types of pages：

1. Modern page:you need to use SPFX Extension to add JS file.
2. Classic page:you could add this file to global jslink.

pnp powershell:

```
$username = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "Password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev -Credentials $cred
 Add-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name "JSLoadAfterSP" -Url /sites/dev/Doc/testFolder/test.js -Sequence 9999 -Scope Site
```

Similar issue:

[How to use JS to inject CSS for specific system pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281581/how-to-use-js-to-inject-css-for-specific-system-pages/281603#281603)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/70373/customization-colour-document-header.html

SPFX Extension add js file:

https://github.com/Amos-IT/SharePoint-FrameWork-Demos/tree/master/react-application-injectjs-master

Comment: Using custom CSS to hide the Quick Launch in modern pages is unsupported: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages

Comment: Yes,Custom CSS via AlternateCSSUrl web property not support,but I could add it via SPFX Extension.